# Use rails-ujs with jquery_ujs in one project?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

To display the photo gallery I use

```
gem 'lightbox-bootstrap-rails', '5.1.0.1'
//= require rails-ujs
//= require lightbox-bootstrap
```

To display the site version for the visually impaired

```
gem 'jquery-bvi-rails', github: 'gordienko/jquery-bvi-rails'
//= require jquery.bvi
```

for it to work I have to add in application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

But when I add them, I lose the gallery’s work(((

I get an error:

```
TypeError: $(this).ekkoLightbox is not a function. (In '$(this).ekkoLightbox()', '$(this).ekkoLightbox' is undefined)
```

Thus, one or the other works for me. 
Or lightbox with rails-ujs. Or  jquery-bvi-rails with jquery_ujs.

How to make them work together?

Comment: `jquery-bvi-rails` does not say it depends on `jquery_ujs`

Comment: @arieljuod
if I don't connect jquery_ujs - pressing the menu button does not work.
After adding jquery_ujs it works.

Comment: If you don't add jquery_ujs (only add jquery), what's the error when you click the menu button? rails-ujs and jquery_ujs only adds some rails related behavior when you use rails ujs options on some elements (like `remote: true` or `data: {alert: 'something'}`) Can't you add only jquery without jquery_ujs?

Comment: @arieljuod then it doesn’t work. There is no error, but nothing happens when the button is pressed.

Comment: If `rails-ujs` is working it is because you are using Rails 5.1 or above. On these version you have to install the `jquery-rails` gem to get support for jQuery. So in your `application.js` you will have: `//= require jquery` and `//= require rails-ujs`.